# jQueryMobile data-native-menu="true" doesn't work on browsers

Tags: jquery

I'm playing with jQueryMobile and with the widget "select".

```
<select id="list"  data-placeholder="true" data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple" data-iconpos="left">
    <option>Country</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
    <option value="br">Brazil</option>
</select>
```

That code works OK in any browser, but in mobile/tablet devices  if I have much information it has a delay, kind of lag, when opening the select menu.
If I change to data-native-menu="true", the mobile/tablet devices are totally fluid but doesn't work on any browser of computer.

Any one have any clue of what could it be? Thanks.

Comment: We are also facing same issue.

Comment: Same problem in here, can check the fiddler for that https://jsfiddle.net/titombo/uxamfLLf/